# Вызов обработчика события слушателя, не кликая по нему

Tags: javascript, input, checkbox

Вопрос такой:
В HTML на инпутах (чекбоксы) висят onclick.
Инпутов много.
И допустим есть условие - когда остались только два активных чекбокса, нужно вызвать у неактивных onclick. Как это сделать?

let message = false

Когда остаются два активных чекбокса то message становится true

message = true;

```js
if(message) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(item => {
    if(!item.checked) {
      item.onclick //вот так не работает, вообще ничего не происходит 
      // item.onclick() - так тоже ничего не происходит
      //консоль вообще ничего не выдает
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ..`item.click()`

Comment: а зачем именно click вызывать? Не достаточно просто checked поменять?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(item => {
    if (item.checked) return;
    // item.click();
    item.dispatchEvent(new Event(`click`, {bubbles: true}));
});
```